# Handsontable: Turn off auto-resizing rows (How to set a fixed height?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

The auto-resizing behaviour is a bit unusual in handsontable. I just want to have fixed row height for all my rows that don't expand unless you click into it, or manually drag it down, like in excel. I also want to manually set that height to the same height for all the rows and not have it calculated based off of the tallest row.

I've tried:

Adding `'height' => 50` to my columns, adding `manualRowResize: true`, and adding in fixed heights for a few rows with `manualRowResize: [50, 50, 50]`, but when my data spans multiple rows (for example, when rendered in html), it doesn't stay at a fixed height.

Answer (score 2):

[Handsontable - Resizing rows and columns](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta6/demo-resizing.html)

Maybe `rowHeights` is what you want.

```
var
    container = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot;

hot = new Handsontable(container, {
    data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(200, 10),
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    colWidths: [55, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80],
    rowHeights: [50, 40, 100], // <-- this one sets fixed row height
    manualColumnResize: true,
    manualRowResize: true
});
```

Comment: that' genius mate! `colWidths:` worked for me! even with `stretchH: 'all',` which is great because then you don't have to think about what value you set : the result is that instad of resising the whole collum when you add a long value it is `overflow: hidden`